# Paperclip with S3 on Rails 3 / uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 using paperclip and get this error when making a new object and referencing the variable:

- the aws-s3 gem is installed
- the s3.yml file has the correct credentials

ie:

```
a = Attachment.new
a.file

NameError: uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Connection
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3.rb:32
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3.rb:31:in `class_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3.rb:31
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:131:in `extended'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:269:in `extend'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:269:in `initialize_storage'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip.rb:372:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip.rb:372:in `attachment_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.3/lib/paperclip.rb:270:in `file'
    from (irb):6
```

and here is what the Attachment model looks like:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  has_attached_file :file,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/uploads/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :bucket => 'bucketname',
    :s3_permissions => :public_read
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out to be a conflict with a different s3 gem that i had left in the gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Mike, did you successfully get aws-s3 working with Rails 3? I am assuming yes, but can you verify as I need to check that out myself.

Comment: yep worked fine with no hitches, just make sure you don't have another S3 gem in your gemfile or you may run into the errors i had.

Comment: Thanks for following up @miketucker, appreciate it.