# facing little trouble while executing test using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

whenever i run this command

```
spec spec/controllers/sample_controller_spec.rb
```

i get the following error

```
/Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:466:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Spec::Adapters (NameError)
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `rake_original_const_missing'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing_not_from_s3_library'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/rspec-1.3.1/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:314:in `plugin_mock_framework'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/rspec-1.3.1/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:139:in `run_examples'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/rspec-1.3.1/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/gems/rspec-1.3.1/bin/spec:5
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/bin/spec:19:in `load'
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/bin/spec:19
    from /Users/suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@helpkit3/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

my gemfile looks like this

```
group :test do
   gem "rspec", "1.3.1"
   gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.3"
   gem "spork", "~> 0.8.0"
   gem "mocha", "~> 0.13.3"
end
```

**Can any one help me in solving this issue i am using rails 2.3.14**

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] if you're using Rails 2.3.14?

Comment: just in case any one can help from  ruby-on-rails-3  group

Comment: do you "require 'spec_helper'" in sample_controller_spec.rb ?

Comment: yes i require it using require File.expand_path("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../spec_helper")

Comment: @suman Anyone watching [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] will also be watching [tag:ruby-on-rails]. You only need [tag:ruby-on-rails]. [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] is for issues specific to Rails version 3.

Comment: okay do you have a solution apart from removing tag...

Comment: Seems like aws gem got problems. Try to read these two threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613741/paperclip-with-s3-on-rails-3-uninitialized-constant-awss3connection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488824/not-able-to-start-rails-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working all the day for solving this error and finally it worked when i changed the mocha version in gemfile from

```
 gem "mocha", "~> 0.13.3"
```

to

```
gem "mocha", "~> 0.12.8"
```